# How to see CUDA thread value using Nvidia NSight in VS 2010?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I would like to know is there a way to look at all the variable values in a given kernel, for example, for threadIdx.x = 1 on what data is it currently working and what's the value of that data?

All is working correctly, so my question is how to see variables like you can do in normal VS, using "Quick watch" or "Add watch", what is their equivalent in NSight?
Thank you, have been struggling for a few hours now.

I have CUDA Info window and CUDA Warp window showing only blockIdx, threadIDx coordinates when debuging through NSight.

```
   __global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if(i<N)
        c[i]=a[i]*b[i];
    // DUmmy code
    if(i<2)
    int k=i;
}
```

My kernel is called like this `addKernel<<<1,N>>>(dev_c,dev_a,dev_b)`and my #DEFINE N 10.

I put breakpoints inside if and else. Output in Warp window is set to show:

```
*(a+i)  *(b+i)  *(c+i)  i

 0          0     -1     0
 2          1     -1     1
 4          4     -1     2
 6          9     -1     3
 8         16     -1     4
```

So, my c is never set up. How so?
thank you

P.S. Can those guys that give me minuses give up always when they see my question I get -1. Thanks again

Comment: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/CUDA_Warp_Watch.htm

Comment: Yes, I know where is CUDA Info and Warp window, but when I Put a breakpoint it doesn't show the variables. HEre is the code and output

Comment: Hello, can you look at it now, thank you

Comment: The people who downvoted your question motivated you to edit it and create a much better question out of it.  So I would say the system is working.  And for the most part, the watch expressions you have placed in the warp window seem to be working as well.  When you set the breakpoints, where did you set them exactly (i.e. on which line)?  If you step to the end of the kernel, does your watch window update with modified values for c[i]?  If this is difficult to do, put a dummy piece of code at the end of the kernel (e.g. printf or what have you) and set a breakpoint there.  Then check c[i]

Comment: No, my watch window does not update values at the end of kernel, but after adding above labeled dummy lines I can see the output now. Thank you, how can I give you points, last question;-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding some dummy lines to my kernel I was able to see value of column c updated. So, that was the solution. I know it sounds trivial , but I have try adding dummy lines before and it didn't work unless extra dummy lines are some other variable, not threads used in calculation of c. So, in short, calculate new threads(or whatever new can go in kernel) and add those extra lines after the variable you would like to see in CUDA Warp window.

Answer (score 2):

The Nsight VSE CUDA Debuggers supports almost all Visual Studio debugger tool windows including the variables views, watch windows, memory views, call stack view, and break points view. These can be opened from the Debug | Windows menu in Visual Studio.

In order to look at values for a specific thread you will have to set a conditional breakpoint with the condition defined to be true for the specific thread ID of interest.

Please see the following topics in the Nsight VSE Manual

1. [Walkthrough: Debugging a CUDA Application](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/debugging_cuda_application.htm)
2. [Set GPU Breakpoint](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/set_gpu_breakpoints.htm)
3. [View Variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/view_variables.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on 555m gt with Compute Capability 2.1 (c[i] = 0).
GTX 660 with Compute Capability 3.0 shows correct values but sometimes c[i] = -1.

With "dummy" line it works just fine in any case (breakpoint in line c[i] = c[i]).

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i]; //if breakpoint will be here c[i] = -1 or 0
    c[i] = c[i]; //breakpoint here guarantees c[i] is correct
}
```